# How do I determine when the scrollview has scrolled at least one screen width in the positive x direction and negative x direction?

Tags: ios, swift

How do I determine when the scrollview has scrolled at least one screen width in the positive x direction and negative x direction (horizontally)? I have been using the following for positive direction:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollview.contentOffset.x > self.view.bounds.width {
         print("Has scrolled one width in + direction")
    }
}
```

Not too sure how to find it for the negative direction. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you start at `contentOffset == .zero`?

Answer (score 0):

We're defining a variable that is responsible of holding the value of your initial x position before scrolling and we're comparing your scrollview's contentOffset.x value to this initial position.

```
var currentContentOffsetX = 0
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if currentContentOffsetX > self.view.bounds.width {
         print("Has scrolled one width in + direction")
    } else if currentContentOffsetX < -self.view.bounds.width {

         print("Has scrolled one width in - direction")
    }
}


// to update the starting X position
func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    currentContentOffsetX = scrollview.contentOffset.x
}
```